# VBA- working on multiple files

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a project in which I would like to have: browsing through files and selecting which to work with, copying and opening those workbooks from destination where their copies were created, then creating a new workbook(excel file) and copying information to it, which every workbook opened earlier would be in a separate sheet.
I have already done browsing through the files but I find it hard to go next.
That's the sample code I have by far.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim i As Integer

   Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
   Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd
      .AllowMultiSelect = True
      .Title = "Please select the file."
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      If .Show = True Then
         For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
            ListBox1.AddItem fd.SelectedItems(i)
         Next
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of iterating through the workbooks.

---

```
  Dim v as variant

  If .Show = True Then
     For Each v In fd.SelectedItems

        'check if this is a valid workbook

        Set WB = Workbooks.Open(v)

        'Your code here

        WB.Close savechanges:=False

     Next v
  End If
```

---

Comment: Thank you, but how do I program those workbooks to copy and open them? Still having problems with that

Comment: Develop and debug the code for a single workbook first.  Then edit your question by adding the code and presenting any problems with it's implementation.

Comment: @Celtas Great!!